# Libsodium PHP: regular key?

Tags: php, cryptography, libsodium

I'm trying to use Libsodium to encrypt and decrypt strings, but I have a question! I'm currently using two functions called safeEncrypt and safeDecrypt, this is the code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Encrypt a message
 * 
 * @param string $message - message to encrypt
 * @param string $key - encryption key
 * @return string
 * @throws RangeException
 */
function safeEncrypt(string $message, string $key): string
{
    if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES) {
        throw new RangeException('Key is not the correct size (must be 32 bytes).');
    }
    $nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES);

    $cipher = base64_encode(
        $nonce.
        sodium_crypto_secretbox(
            $message,
            $nonce,
            $key
        )
    );
    sodium_memzero($message);
    sodium_memzero($key);
    return $cipher;
}

/**
 * Decrypt a message
 * 
 * @param string $encrypted - message encrypted with safeEncrypt()
 * @param string $key - encryption key
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function safeDecrypt(string $encrypted, string $key): string
{   
    $decoded = base64_decode($encrypted);
    $nonce = mb_substr($decoded, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES, '8bit');
    $ciphertext = mb_substr($decoded, SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES, null, '8bit');

    $plain = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open(
        $ciphertext,
        $nonce,
        $key
    );
    if (!is_string($plain)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid MAC');
    }
    sodium_memzero($ciphertext);
    sodium_memzero($key);
    return $plain;
}
```

I'm then using these functions like this:

```
<?php
// This refers to the previous code block.
require "safeCrypto.php"; 

// Do this once then store it somehow:
$key = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
$message = 'We are all living in a yellow submarine';

$ciphertext = safeEncrypt($message, $key);
$plaintext = safeDecrypt($ciphertext, $key);

echo "Encrypted: " . $ciphertext;
echo "\r\n";
echo "Decrypted: " . $plaintext;
echo "\r\n";
echo "--------";
echo "\r\n";
echo "KEY: " . $key;
```

My concern is that the key isn't in normal ascii, it's something else that I don't quite understand, like this: `&w��x�QK��|D���z�����`

Can I somehow modify the functions to make them generate and use keys that look something like this: `S3d3F45g6H7jJ8kG7`? I need it like this so that I can pass the keys in URL.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sodium_bin2hex($key)` to encode the key from binary to hexadecimal, but don't forget to decode it with `sodium_hex2bin($key)` before using it for encryption/ decryption.

To address the *I need it like this so that I can pass the keys in URL.* part of your question: you should never do that. Encryption keys must be kept as secure as possible, and passing them through URLs is not secure at all.